# How do I tie several methods to a single event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a start button (listed as css element start_button) that when click will fire several events such as, increments a score by one point, decrements a timer by one second,calls a picture and changes a couple CSS elements.

I have functions that are called on by a .on event listener that will fire (or so I hope)when called on by the a function called start. I have yet to figure how to tie the even into the function. Thank you for your contribution.

function start () 

            $('#start_button').on('click', function(){
            incrementor();//calls on the stand alone function
            $('#start_button').on('click', function(){
            addMole();
            $('#start_button').on('click', function(){
            timer();
            $('#start_button').on('click', function(){
            incrementor();
            alert (xPosistion());
            alert (yPosistion());
        });
        });
        }); 
        });

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nest all of these into the first on hook.

```
jQuery('#start_button').on('click', function() {
    functionNameOne();
    functionNameTwo();
    functionNameThree();
    //etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery API deos not support registering multiple handlers for a single event in a single call.

You can do something like this to make it look prettier:

```
function foo(event) {...};
function bar(event) {...};

obj.on('click', foo);
obj.on('click', bar);
```